# How does React and Django actually work together

Tags: django, reactjs

Hello I have now just started with learning React however I am getting a bit confused how does this two i.e Django and React actually get to work with one another.

1. With routing from page to page is this handled by Django or React or this is a choice that one can take self?
2. I am also wondering when dealing with normal Django templates same applies when using react or what?
3. I have been searching where I can get a full blog/write-up where I can learn how to integrate the two and the best practices to this two but could not seem to find the one that is answering me or I just did not understand because I am a Beginner in this domain.
4. Will this be best practice(This is the idea that I had on how people use this two frameworks) the idea that I had is one just builds a backend api that which then React can use however the rest such as page routing is all handled by React is this true or best practise or the is a better way in which people handle this.

Can you please give me a detailed explanation on how this two are actually merged and how they work and if there is a place where I can read up and learn more please also give the resources so that I can go and read and learn more on how this is actually done and handled

Comment: It all depends on how you want to design your project, e.g. whether you want to separate the API and the UI or have full-integration of React inside Django templates. Here's an old post on using `django-webpack-loader` to integrate django and react: https://owais.lone.pw/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/

Comment: So basically you can have React handle everything from your routing etc and then have Django for your API?

So what would be best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. With routing from page to page is this handled by Django or React or this is a choice     that one can take self?

You could try to navigate to a route but Django would override the routes, most instances of this people adopt a route catchall so that all your react routes can be handled by the react side yet still having access to defined Django routes.

> 2. I am also wondering when dealing with normal Django templates same applies when using     react or what?
> 3. I have been searching where I can get a full blog/write-up where I can learn how to integrate the two and the best practices to this two
>    but could not seem to find the one that is answering me or I just did
>    not understand because I am a Beginner in this domain.
> 4. Will this be best practice(This is the idea that I had on how people use this two frameworks) the idea that I had is one just builds
>    a backend api that which then React can use however the rest such as
>    page routing is all handled by React is this true or best practise or
>    the is a better way in which people handle this.

Have Django handle some routing and forcing it to send unknown routes to React to be handled is a bit dodgy but for smaller projects would not be a problem at all. I usually recommend people to create a Django backend with REST support and then have the frontend React separate. This way you can have everything separate and work nicely together especially if you're looking to change your frontend in the future. Your fourth question is definitely spot on and it'll prevent a lot of headaches in the future.

Definitely give [this](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/) blog a try and see where how you get on. Also, just give a Google for 'django-rest react' for more tutorials.

Comment: Oh so what I am getting from your answer and the other persons comment separating the front-end and the back-end is good? Meaning that I have Django handle the back-end  only then use React from front-end and routing? Is this what you meant?

Comment: Separating them is better in terms of flexibility and ability to change your frontend quite painlessly in the future. React will handle the front-end routing and consume the Django-Rest api via components. Django will be turned into a RESTful api and React will be used to interact with it and handle all the routing you need.